# Call a fonction from message box Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to call the fonction (submit) after clicking on the message box. With this code I have to reclick on button everytime after the messagebox but would appreciate if the timer launch automatically after clicking on the message box.

If anyone have a clue I will appreciate.

The following code :

```
import time
from tkinter import *



root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

root.geometry("300x250")
root['background']='#39E5F9'

root.title("Time To Drink Water")

minute = StringVar()
second = StringVar()
minute.set("45")
second.set("00")

minuteEntry = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Arial", 35, ""),
                textvariable=minute,justify='center')
minuteEntry.place(x=50, y=60)
secondEntry = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Arial", 35, ""),
                textvariable=second,justify='center')
secondEntry.place(x=170, y=60)

def submit():
    # stored in here : 2700 = 45 mins
 temp = 2700
 while temp > -1:
    # divmod(firstvalue = temp//60, secondvalue = temp%60)
    mins, secs = divmod(temp, 60)
    if mins > 60:
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
    minute.set("{0:2d}".format(mins))
    second.set("{0:2d}".format(secs))

    root.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    if (temp == 0):
         messagebox.showinfo("Time Countdown", "Time To Drink !")
    temp -= 1

def go():
  btn = Button(root, text='Goodbye dehydration!', bd='6',
             command=submit)
  btn.place(x=90, y=160)

go()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should not call `sleep` as it will force your entire GUI to freeze. There are hundreds of questions and answers on this site about using `sleep` with tkinter.

Comment: don't run `sleep` and don't use `while` because both freeze GUI (in any framework, and in any language). You should use `root.after(1000, function)` to run function again after 1000ms. And use `if` instead of `while`

Comment: it may need to run two functions - first button has to run function which set values at start and next run function which will update data and it will use `root.after()` to run itself again after 1000ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messagebox` is waiting for your click so you can run `submit()` after `messagebox` and it will run it after clicking in `messagebox`

But you shouldn't use `while` and `sleep` because it may freeze GUI (in any framework, and in any language). You can use `root.after(1000, function)` to run function again after 1000ms (1s) and it will work as `sleep` and `while` together.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import messagebox

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def submit():
    update_counter(2700)
    
def update_counter(temp):    
    if temp > -1:   # `if` instead of `while` because `after` will work as loop
        # divmod(firstvalue = temp//60, secondvalue = temp%60)
        mins, secs = divmod(temp, 60)
        if mins > 60:
            hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        minute.set("{:02d}".format(mins))  # use `:02` to get `09` instead of ` 9` (with space)
        second.set("{:02d}".format(secs))

        temp -= 1
        root.after(1000, update_counter, temp)  # run again after 1000ms
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Time Countdown", "Time To Drink !")
        root.after(0, update_counter, 2700)  # run again after 0ms
        #update_counter(2700)  # run again
        
# --- main ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables

running = False
temp = 2700
root = tk.Tk()

minute = tk.StringVar(root)
second = tk.StringVar(root)
minute.set("45")
second.set("00")

minute_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=3, textvariable=minute, font=("Arial", 35, ""), justify='center')
minute_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

second_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=3, textvariable=second, font=("Arial", 35, ""), justify='center')
second_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Goodbye dehydration!', command=submit)
btn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

There is other problem. You can click button two times and it will run two `update_counter()` at the same time. It may need to disable button, or you would have to use boolean variable - ie. `running = False` - to control if it has to run `update_counter()` or not.

Comment: The `showinfo()` will be kept calling after `temp` reaches -1 due to the line `root.after(0, update_counter, temp)` inside `update_counter()`.  I think it should be `root.after(0, submit)` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I should set `2700` instead of `temp` :). I fixed it.

Comment: My health thanks you guys I really appreciate :)